# Looking for peers in a private run blockchain using geth

Tags: go-ethereum

I've installed geth on ubuntu 16.04 (xenial). After creating the following genesis.json file:

```
{
  "config": {

        "chainId": 4568,

        "homesteadBlock": 0,

        "eip150Block": 0,

        "eip155Block": 0,

        "eip158Block": 0

    },

  "alloc"      : {},

  "difficulty" : "0x400",

  "extraData"  : "",

  "gasLimit"   : "0x7A1200",

  "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",

  "timestamp"  : "0x00"

}
```

I created an account (same as eth.coinbase) and launched miner.start().  The hashrate is >0 and I receive the following message "Looking for peers" for more than 2 hours. 
I don't understand:

- why do I need to look for peers in a privately run blockchain?
- why is it taking so long ?

Best

Comment: you need to add the other nodes using admin.addpeer('the node uri") in the geth cli. https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network#common-problems-with-connectivity

Comment: Yep, went to fast and didn't properly read... https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/peer-to-peer. Thank you for the reply

Comment: should admin.peer be in genesis block ?